# Running single Python Selenium test on Bamboo CI

Tags: python, selenium, ssh, bamboo

I have a dedicated server which we are using for Selenium (Python) testing only.

So I want to SSH in that server and run a single Python Selenium test. I have Bamboo running on the other server. Is it possible through Bamboo SSH job?

This is my script for my Bamboo SSH task:

```
cd ~
cd tms2_selenium
source venv/bin/activate
behave features/login.feature
```

and I get this error:

```
Exception WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
build   07-Jul-2017 17:17:41      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.26.436382 (70eb799287ce4c2208441fc057053a5b07ceabac),platform=Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 x86_64)

Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open display before opening chromedriver:

```
  context.display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
  context.display.start()
  options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
  context.browser = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver',chrome_options=options)
```